# Trackpad not working after update to Ubuntu 14.10 on Dell Inspiron 15R

Tags: touchpad, dell

When I updated from 14.04 to 14.10 I noticed my track-pad cursor and left and right mouse clickers were not working. I have tried looking this issue up and can not find any solutions anywhere. If anyone could help me that would be amazing, I am using a wired mouse to my USB port for a temporary fix. I have a Dell Inspiron 15R.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/284694/ubuntu-12-10-keyboard-touchpad-not-working-on-acer-aspire-v3-551-7844

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal, type:

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c_hid.conf
```

then type the following into that file:

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

Save the file and restart your system, now check whether the touchpad is working fine.