# 14.10 Trackpad works correctly on live CD, but not after installation

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, trackpad

I purchased a Dell Inspiron 7746 notebook, and have installed Ubuntu 14.10 on alongside Windows.

All has worked well so far, but I am having a frustrating getting the trackpad to work correctly. The trackpad worked great when running from the Live CD, but once I actually installed the OS, I found that it's operation to be undesirable.

Here are the issues I am having:

- Tap to click does not work. Clicks are only registered when pressing the clickpad
- Two-finger tap to right-click does not work. In fact, right-clicking is not possible at all. Pressing the clickpad in the right-click area does not register as a right-click.
- Two finger scrolling does work, however, after scrolling, any single finger trackpad action is also registered as a scroll. The only way to fix this is to two-finger scroll again.
- Trackpad does not disable while typing.

Here are some of the workarounds I have tried after doing some googling:

- Ran `synclient tapbutton 1=1`
- Added `Option "TapButton1" "1"` to `50-synaptics.conf`
- Did a fresh install of 14.10 (several times, actually)

Perhaps the most frustrating thing about this is that the trackpad works beautifully on the live CD, just not when the OS is installed. Using a wireless USB mouse now, but would love to get this issue resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working now! Found a solution on this question:

[Trackpad not working when updated to Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557096/trackpad-not-working-when-updated-to-ubuntu-14-10)

> In the terminal, type:
>
> `` sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c_hid.conf` ``
>
> then type the following into that file.
>
> `blacklist i2c_hid`
>
> Save the file and restart your system, now check whether the touchpad is working fine